# How to avoid null date record where there is record with given date else need to get record with null date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table in which for same AgencyMaster ID I have multiple entry with different effectiveStart date and effectiveEnd date, and one entry with both effectiveEnd and effectiveStart as null.

If I'm giving date which is doesn't have entry then it should return record with effectiveEnd and effectiveStart as null else corresponding record with that particular effectiveStart and effectiveEnd date, but here my issue is that it's return record with null date and record with particular date, total 2 records so how to avoid this.

```
select AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.AgencyBillingSettingMasterID, *
from AgencyBillingSettingsMaster
where (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is not null and 
       AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is not null and 
       (convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)>=effectivePeriodStart and
        convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)<effectivePeriodEnd)
        or (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is null and
            AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is null))
```

attached table screen shot

[image]

Comment: Why would you have a null start date ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you misplaced the closing parenthesis. Each condition should be separate, but in your current code all comes under single condition.

The code will solve your issue:

```
select AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.AgencyBillingSettingMasterID, *
from AgencyBillingSettingsMaster
where (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is not null and 
       AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is not null and 
       (convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)>=effectivePeriodStart and 
        convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)<effectivePeriodEnd)) -- here the first condition need to close
        or -- the second condition should have another block
          (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is null and
           AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in MySQL to use the function [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) in combination with `UNION` in order to get a conditional union:

```
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE your_condition_for_existing_dates_here
UNION ALL
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND your_condition_for_null_dates_here
```

Your query will be like this:

```
select AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.AgencyBillingSettingMasterID, *
from AgencyBillingSettingsMaster
where (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is not null and 
       AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is not null and 
       (convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)>=effectivePeriodStart and
        convert(datetime,@EffectivePeriod)<effectivePeriodEnd)
union all
select AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.AgencyBillingSettingMasterID, *
from AgencyBillingSettingsMaster
where found_rows() = 0 
        and (AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodStart is null and
            AgencyBillingSettingsMaster.effectivePeriodEnd is null))
```